# Conditions for two sets to have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have two sets $A$ and $B$, I wonder why the following two conditions imply that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

I. $A\subset B$ and there exists $f:A\to B$, and $g:B\to A$ such that $f\circ g=Id_{B}$

II. $|A\setminus B |=|B\setminus A|$

Comment: II. implies $A = B$ since $A\setminus B = \emptyset$.

Comment: @amsmath not at all, take $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$

Comment: @Vsotvep $A\subset B$ is required.

Comment: For I., not for II.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I.

This is an application of the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Since $A\subset B$, the identity function $\mathrm{id}_A:A\to B$ is an injective function. On the other hand, show that $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_B$ implies that $g$ is injective.

By the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem it follows that $|A|=|B|$.

### II.

Remember that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection $A\to B$.

If $|A\setminus B|=|B\setminus A|$, then there is a bijection $f:A\setminus B\to B\setminus A$. Note that $A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$ and $B=(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)$. Clearly there is a bijection $g:A\cap B\to A\cap B$. Can you use $f$ and $g$ to make a bijection $A\to B$?

Comment: $f+g$? Like conditioning on whether the input is in $A\setminus B$ or not.

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 exactly, you just have to make sure it is a bijection.